# Rotating divs on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am hope someone is able to help. I have been struggling with this for a couple of days now. I am using jQuery to rotate divs on click. It worked until I needed two functionalities on one page. So, I have two groups of divs to rotate in two places on one page and it is rotating both groups regardless of where I click. For example, I am using arrows to rotate div content and if I use the second set of arrows it is rotating both sets of div content at the same time. I would like these two to be independent - be able to rotate one group of divs without the other.

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#cslide-slides").cslide();
    });
```

```css
    /*=Slides
    ----------------------------------------------- */
    .cslide-slides-master {
      overflow: hidden;
     }
    
    .cslide-slides-master:last-child {
      margin-bottom: 0; }
    
    .cslide-slides-container {
      visibility: hidden; }
    
    .cslide-slide {
      float: left;
     }
    /* prev next buttons */
    .cslide-prev-next {
      display: none;
      -webkit-touch-callout: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -khtml-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
      user-select: none; }
    
    .cslide-prev, .cslide-next {
      display: inline-block;
      float: right;
    
      padding: 10px 5px;
    
      cursor: pointer; }
    
    .cslide-prev.cslide-disabled:hover,
    .cslide-next.cslide-disabled:hover {
     }
    
    .cslide-disabled {
      opacity: 0.3; }
```

```html
<div id="Cell">
    <section id="cslide-slides" class="cslide-slides-master clearfix">
    
                <div class="cslide-slides-container clearfix">
                    <div class="cslide-slide">h4>Insert update headline here</h4>
                        <p>Some text that describes this update</p>
    
                    </div>
                    <div class="cslide-slide">h4>Update 2</h4>
                        <p>Some text that describes this update</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cslide-slide"><h4>Update 3</h4><p>Some text that describes this update</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cslide-slide">h4>Update 4</h4><p>Some text that describes this update</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cslide-slide"><h4>Update 5</h4><p>Some text that describes this update</p>
                    </div>
    
                </div>
                <div class="cslide-prev-next clearfix"><span class="cslide-next"><img src="images/Arrows_navigation_right.png" alt="Right" width="20" height="20"></span>
                    <span class="cslide-prev"><img src="images/Arrows_navigation_left.png" alt="Left" width="20" height="20"></span>
    
                </div>
            </section><!-- /sliding content section -->
    
    
      </div>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      
      <div id="Cell">
    
    <p class="line">&nbsp;</p>
    
    <section id="cslide-slides" class="cslide-slides-master clearfix">
    
                <div class="cslide-slides-container clearfix">
                    <div class="cslide-slide"><h4>Insert update headline here</h4>
                        <p>Some text that describes this update</p>
    
                    </div>
                    <div class="cslide-slide"><h4>Update 2</h4>
                        <p>Some text that describes this update</p><a href="PolicyUpdates.html#PolicyUpdate2">Read more</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cslide-slide"><h4>Update 3</h4><p>Some text that describes this update</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cslide-slide"><h4>Update 4</h4><p>Some text that describes this update</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cslide-slide"><h4>Update 5</h4><p>Some text that describes this update</p>
                    </div>
    
                </div>
                <div class="cslide-prev-next clearfix"><span class="cslide-next"><img src="images/Arrows_navigation_right.png" alt="Right" width="20" height="20"></span>
                    <span class="cslide-prev"><img src="images/Arrows_navigation_left.png" alt="Left" width="20" height="20"></span>
    
                </div>
            </section><!-- /sliding content section -->
    </div>






    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cslide.js">
```

Comment: You need to initialize a separate instance of cslide for each slider. Also, IDs should be unique and not reused on the same page. That is what classes are for. FWIW I would use a newer slider. The one you are using is 4 years old. One more thing, use `margin` and `padding` to create whitespace, not `&nbsp;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize a separate instance of `cslide` for each slider. Also, IDs should be unique and not reused on the same page. That is what classes are for.

Create a unique ID for each slider and initialize with the class if the plugin allows. Otherwise, use the unique IDs.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cslide.js"></script>  
<script>
$( document ).ready( function () {
  $( '.cslide-slides-master' ).cslide();
} );
</script>
```

FWIW use a newer slider, the one you are using has not been updated in 4 years.

Comment: Thank you so much. The solution was so simple (now that you told me) and I just missed it. Thank you so much for your help, feedback and suggestion.

Comment: Which route did you go? Class or ID? Please accept the solution.

Comment: I created a unique ID and initialized a separate class for each slider. How do I accept the answer? It is telling me that my low reputation is limiting me in what I can do. My vote was recorded but not being publicly displayed. Is that what you mean?

Comment: The up/downvote ticker in the upper lefthand corner should have a checkmark below it that you can click to accept an answer.